# What is the name and command for the symbol next to the infinity?

Tags: symbols

[image: The picture in question.]

I want to know what the name and command of the symbol next to the infinity is. This is a partial screenshot from my homework. I'm expected to submit a typeset homework that requires this symbol in the answer.

Anyone know what it is and its command?

Comment: It's a prime, which is often seen in superscript, such as `f'`. You can get this oversized prime with `\prime`.

Comment: @ChrisS Better yet, that's the *normalsized* prime. However, since we usually use primes as a superscript, `'` gives the correctly sized prime in a superscript (like `^{\prime}`).

Comment: That symbol is contained in Table 201 (p 65) of the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf): `\prime`

Comment: @Manuel -- the "normalsized prime" in traditional metal type is smaller and in superscript position.  this larger version is tex-specific, and was created thus so that it could be handled with the same mechanism used to set all other super- and subscripts (yes, prime is sometimes used as a subscript).  math follows typesetting rules quite different from those for ordinary text, and this accounts for some of the nontraditional font decisions of tex, which "puts math first".